# CSS trapezoid shape clickable area issue in chrome browser

Tags: html, css, perspective, css-shapes

I'm trying to get a trapezoidal perspective shape to have the whole area be clickable. I've gotten it to work in Firefox and even IE, but Chrome isn't cooperating too well.

Here's a fiddle with the shape and a link: http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/1/ 
As you can tell, the link doesn't become active until you hover over the 'area' part of the text. In other browsers, the whole height of the shape is clickable.

I read that Chrome renders a perspective image differently and perhaps that's why it's not doing what it's supposed to.

Here's my CSS:

```
.prodcaptions {
width:136px;
height: 85px;
position:relative;
left:10%;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
letter-spacing: 1.6px;
color: #000;
}
.prodcaptions:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
border-radius:1px;
box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #27628e;
top:-5%;
bottom:-11%;
left:-1%;
right:-5%;
-webkit-transform:perspective(40em) rotateX(-45deg);
transform:perspective(40em) rotateX(-45deg);
}

.prodcaptions a {
z-index:999;
position:relative;
height: 85px;
display: block;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: How about you transform the a inside as well? - apparently it does not matter as the area is not extended past the text portion. Still testing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. This is the first time I've worked with these types of shapes!

Comment: have a look at this: **http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/2/**.. Is this acceptable? (I removed the `:before`, so the text is also in perspective, all the text gets the pointer cursor now)

Comment: @myfunkyside That's kind of better. It's just that the space under the word 'area' is still no clickable, until you hover down until you hit the bottom line of the shape. I wish the whole trapezoid height area could be clickable.

Comment: yeah, still workin on it..

Comment: Think i may have got it: http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/7/

Comment: Why not make the container the link itself?  http://jsfiddle.net/n0pLypL8/

Comment: @onetrickpony Exactly the same as my thought http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/8/

Comment: @onetrickpony I think so far that's the most elegant way to do it (as in it doesn't skew the text). Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have look at this code:

```
.prodcaptions {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    perspective: 150px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0;
}
a{
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;  
    transform: rotateX(-15deg);
}
```

Seems to work the way you want it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uh6f6/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this shape for link trapazoid shape - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2fhbao5/)

**Advantage** - you can change skew property to change angle of shape! Easy and effective! Reverse value for reverse shape!

[image]

---

**html**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here!</a>
```

**css**

```
 a {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    /* custom sizes */
    width: 136px;
    height: 85px;
    /* demo-only decoration */
    margin: 100px auto;
    font: 16px/50px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
}
a:before, a:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    /* demo-only decoration */
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: orange;
}
a:before {
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    left: 25px;
}
a:after {
    transform: skew(20deg);
    right: 25px;
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: It looks great and everything, just that it needs to be transparent in the middle as part of the design. Is that possible with your suggestion?